# Remove Spaces between lines in a text file

Tags: unix, line, space

```
TCAMPBMG0064X344F4E1              1     47552    85.280   557.600   11300     

TCAMPBMG0064X352F8E1              1     61265    85.280   718.400   11463     

TCAMPBMG0064X344F4E1              1     47552    85.280   557.600   11300     

TCAMPBMG0064X352F8E1              1     61265    85.280   718.400   11463
```

I have a file like this. I want to remove spaces between the two lines .i.e. I want the file to be like this.

```
TCAMPBMG0064X344F4E1              1     47552    85.280   557.600   11300     
TCAMPBMG0064X352F8E1              1     61265    85.280   718.400   11463     
TCAMPBMG0064X344F4E1              1     47552    85.280   557.600   11300     
TCAMPBMG0064X352F8E1              1     61265    85.280   718.400   11463
```

How to change the file to eliminate spaces above and below each line in UNIX?
I tried `:%s/\s//g` but the spaces above and below the lines remained

Answer (score 4):

Either use grep or sed as like below to remove the blank lines

```
grep -v '^ *$' $files

sed '/^ *$/d' $files
```

Comment: Also, in `vim` (which is what the OP seems to have started with), you can use `:g/^\s*$/d`.

Comment: Can u please help me do it like a search and replace?search for the space after the line and remove it

Comment: Thanks guys. Did a cheat here. Copied the contents onto the desktop and opened it using notepad++ and performed Remove Empty LInes . :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a very short one:

```
awk '$0' file
```

If the string is not empty then the condition is evaluated as true - note that `{print $0}` is the default block in `awk` so it can be omitted if this is the only action you want to perform.

#### Test

```
$ awk '$0' file
TCAMPBMG0064X344F4E1              1     47552    85.280   557.600   11300     
TCAMPBMG0064X352F8E1              1     61265    85.280   718.400   11463     
TCAMPBMG0064X344F4E1              1     47552    85.280   557.600   11300     
TCAMPBMG0064X352F8E1              1     61265    85.280   718.400   11463
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `sed` command to delete blank lines:

```
sed '/^$/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep to find lines that are not blank, e.g.:

```
grep -e '[^\n]' temp.txt > temp.out
```